# What is this set theory question even asking me?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

I saw some other questions that had similar titles and checked them out, but none of them seemed to match this format. The question I have is:

One quarter of the five-element subsets of $\{1, 2, 3, \cdots, n\}$
contain the element $7$. Determine $n (\ge 5)$.

I don't understand what this question wants me to do. I understand what a subset is, and I know what elements are, but I don't know what "Determine $n (\ge 5)$" is asking me to do.

Comment: "What value must $n$ be in order for exactly one quarter of the five-element subsets of $\{1, 2, 3, \cdots, n\}$ to contain 7? $n$ must be $\ge 5$."

Comment: @Matthew That's exactly the information I was looking for. If you had posted this as an answer instead of a comment I'd be marking this as answered by you. Thanks.

Comment: Glad I could help :) I am very much a mathematics neophyte, so it's probably better for me to have a low reputation anyway :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:** There are $\dbinom{n}{5}$ five-element subsets.

How many five-element subsets are there that contain the number $7$? We have to choose $4$ elements from the remaining $n-1$ to keep company with the $7$.

For what value(s) of $n\ge 5$ is the second number one-quarter of the first?

**Remark:** The insistence that $n\ge 5$ is a bit picky, but in principle necessary. Suppose for example that $n=4$. There are $0$ ways to choose a five-element subset of $\{1,2,3,4\}$. There are also $0$ ways to choose a five-element subset that contains $7$. And $\frac{0}{4}=0$!

Comment: Thanks to Matthew who commented above I know what it's asking me to do. You're answer, though very helpful, didn't really answer what I was supposed to be doing, but guided me towards the first steps to  find that answer. I certainly appreciate the response, though!

Comment: Get an expression for the number of five-element subsets that contain $7$. I hinted on how to do that. Set that equal to $1/4$ of $\binom{n}{5}$. You get an equation in $n$. Solve. Want to leave the rest to you, unless you run into trouble.

Comment: @Dave: I think you might misunderstand, as I believe you will answer "must be $\ge 5$". This is not the answer, just an obvious necessary condition. AN guided you in the eight direction: you can calculate a value $n$ using the above: $\frac{1}{4} = \frac{\binom{n-1}{4}}{\binom{n}{5}$, which is what Andre pointed our. I tried finding a clever way of doing this, failed, and by trial and error it's at least 10; but one will work as your teacher asked you to determine it.

Comment: Sorry for typos which I cannot correct on my phone, and won't be home in 5 mins...if a moderator can add the closing dollar, appreciated.

Comment: @gnometorule - That's what I came up with based on what Matthew told me as well. Andre helped me with coming up with some of the combinations that would be used in the formula, but I wasn't sure what to do with them since what I didn't know is that the question wanted me to find the value of n such that one quarter of the sets would include a 7.

Comment: @gnometorule: Don't need clever, one just expands, almost everything cancels. But if you feel like slightly clever, use identity $\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n}{k}\binom{n-1}{k-1}$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas - The edits you have made now include the answer, and since Matthew only commented, you've got the credit. Thanks very much!

Comment: @Dave: The question you actually asked was first answered by you. I think you do not get points "credit" if you accept it, but it is certainly possible to accept your own answer. I hope you will now find it straightforward to finish the calculation.

Comment: @AndréNicolas - Yes, I did transfer Matthew's comment into an answer, but I wasn't concerned with credit, I was just wanting to wrap up the question so those answering could help others. I'm glad I wasn't able to accept it right away, though, as much more insight has been provided on this problem since then.

Answer (score 2):

"What value must n be in order for exactly one quarter of the five-element subsets of {1,2,3,⋯,n} to contain 7? n must be ≥5." Credit goes to @Matthew in the first comment on my question.